# How to compose multiple TypeScript class decorators?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a family of class decorators that I repeat over many classes. Something similar to this:

```
@foo
@bar
@baz
export class MyClass { /* ..... */ }
```

Since I'm using those three decorators across multiple classes, I'd really like to break that down into one decorator, like so:

```
@standard
export class MyClass { /* ... */ }
```

I've tried to create a new class decorator that chains the decorator calls like this:

```
export function standard<ReturnType>(ctor: Constructor<ReturnType>) {
    return baz(bar(foo(ctor)));
}
```

The TypeScript handbook says applying multiple decorators should evaluate similar to function composition, which is why I figured I should be able to chain them together. However, come compile time (using TypeScript 1.8) I get an error similar to

`Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Type 'Constructor<ReturnType>' is not assignable to type 'void'.`

Is there a way I can construct this 'wrapper' decorator to simplify my code?

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I fill in the blanks. Can you post a full example that duplicates your error?

Comment: Trying to give a better example for you lead me to the fix!  Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an attempt to build a more complete version of my problem for @David, I figured out where I was going wrong.

A more, full example:

```
interface Constructor<T> { new(...args: any[]): T }
interface A { a: number; }
interface B { b: number; }
interface C { c: number; }

function foo(Target: Constructor<A>): Constructor<A>{ 
    // do some stuff to the constructor
    return Target;
}
function bar(Target: Constructor<B>): Constructor<B> { 
    // do some stuff to the constructor
    return Target;
}
function baz(Target: Constructor<C>): Constructor<C> {
    // ....
    return Target;
}

function standard(ctor: Constructor<A & B & C>): Constructor<A & B & C> {
    return baz(bar(foo(ctor)));
}

@foo
@bar
@baz
class MyClass implements A, B, C { a=1;b=2;c=3;d=6; }
```

There was some implicit typing in my actual code that somewhat hid the problem from me. And apparently I couldn't read compiler output correctly.

The problem was with how I declared my decorators:

```
function foo(Target: Constructor<A>): Constructor<A> { }
```

Needed to be

```
function foo<T extends A>(Target: Constructor<T>): Constructor<T> {}
```

I noticed if I set the return types in the decorators to `any` the compile errors went away.  The extra generic parameter let the type info cleanly flow through the decorators.  Otherwise I believe it saw (essentially) that `Constructor<MyClass>` could not be assigned an instance of `Constructor<A>` (since `A` is missing the other interfaces). Also curiously, I got more errors in the decorators to pop up if I added that declaration of `d` in `MyClass`.

So in closing - when working with class decorators, be careful with your generics, or just return `any`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put it like this:

```
export function foo(target: any)
{
    return target;
}

export function bar(target: any)
{
    return target;
}

export function baz(target: any)
{
    return target;
}

export function standard<T>() 
{
    return (target: { new(): T}) =>
    {
        return foo(bar(baz(target)));
    }
}

@foo
@bar
@baz
export class MyClass  { /* ... */ }

@standard<MyClass>()
export class MyClassA { /* ... */ }
```