# Typescript: Apply two method decorator factories using one statement

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator

In Typescript, I have about 10 methods that should all be decorated as `@A()` and `@B()`. For easier maintenance, I want to be able to decorate them as `@C()` - I make Typescript apply both `@A()` and `@B()`.

To clarify, this is the existing code:

```js
class MyClass {
  @A()
  @B()
  method1() {}

  @A()
  @B()
  method2() {}
}
```

I want to create a decorator factory `C` that will make the following code equivalent to the above:

```js
class MyClass {
  @C()
  method1() {}

  @C()
  method2() {}
}
```

Is that possible? [The handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) says:

> When multiple decorators apply to a single declaration, their evaluation is similar to function composition in mathematics. In this model, when composing functions f and g, the resulting composite (f ∘ g)(x) is equivalent to f(g(x)).

So it should be possible to create this composition in a programmatic way.

**EDIT** for anyone coming here for a solution within NestJS (which was my original issue) -- even though there doesn't seem to be a generic Typescript solution, [there is one specific for NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#decorator-composition).

Comment: At least related; one of the answers shows doing a compound decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744981/combine-several-host-bindings-into-one-single-decorator (It's uglier than one might hope.)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026224/how-to-compose-multiple-typescript-class-decorators) one as well, and see if it helps.

Comment: Looks like it's important whether the decorators are straight-up decorators or decorator factories.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder looks like the bigger issue is making it work with decorator factories.

Comment: @noamtm - Yup. Non-factories are pretty easy.